# Under what circumstances must I use py-files option of spark-submit?

Tags: python, apache-spark

Just poking around spark-submit, I was under the impression that if my application has got dependencies on other .py files then I have to distribute them using the py-files option (see [bundling your applications dependencies](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#bundling-your-applications-dependencies)). I took that to mean any file had to be declared using py-files yet the following works fine... two `.py` files:

`spark_submit_test_lib.py`:

```
def do_sum(sc) :
  data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  distData = sc.parallelize(data)
  return distData.sum()
```

and `spark_submit_test.py`:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from spark_submit_test_lib import do_sum
conf = SparkConf().setAppName('JT_test')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
print do_sum(sc)
```

submitted using:

```
spark-submit --queue 'myqueue' spark_submit_test.py
```

All worked fine. Code ran, yields the correct result, spark-submit terminates gracefully.
However, I would have thought having read the documentation that I would have had to do this:

```
spark-submit --queue 'myqueue' --py-files spark_submit_test_lib.py spark_submit_test.py
```

That still worked of course. I'm just wondering why the former worked as well. Any suggestions?

Comment: thank you @cricket_007 for the edit. A very useful one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be submitting this in local environment where your driver and executors runs on the same machine , that is the the reason it worked ,but if you deploy in cluster and try to run from there  you have to use --pf-files option.

Please check the [link](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/#running-the-examples-and-shell) for more details

Comment: Thank you @arunakiran-nulu. I'm not actually explicitly specifying a  deploy mode so is there a way to programatically determine the deploy mode once the application is running? I added   


print 'spark.master: {0}'.format(sc._conf.get("spark.master"))
print 'spark.submit.deployMode: {0}'.format(sc._conf.get("spark.submit.deployMode"))

which yields:

spark.master: yarn-client
spark.submit.deployMode: client

Is `client` deploy-mode the same as what you called local?

Comment: you can check all these in spark UI ,environment tab , if you are running in local the url is http://localhost:4040/environment/

Comment: figured it out, thank you Arunikiran. `spark-submit --queue 'myqueue' --py-files spark_submit_test_lib.py --deploy-mode cluster --master yarn spark_submit_test.py`